# Fetch Matlab Function

Tags: matlab, fetch

I was wondering if there is a way to download datas from yahoo with "fetch function" and save this data into a NxT matrix, where T is the number of the tickers.

The main problem is that i wish I could do this in a GUI with a popupmenu which allows you to choose among T securities.

Thank you

Comment: Would something like [urlread](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/expanding-urlreads-capabilities/) work for you?

Comment: I suggest you read the article and documentation to see.

Comment: Just gave a quick look. It seems it downloads the contents of a webpage, right?
I'll test it in Matlab